# System.CommandLine seems to be incorrectly parsing arguments that are file paths that end with a trailing slash

Tags: c#, console, command-line-arguments, system.commandline

I am creating a console app using the [System.CommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.commandline) library. I have found what I think is a bug but would like to check if I'm just missing something.

```
using System.CommandLine;

class Program
{
    static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sourceOption = new Option<DirectoryInfo>(
            "--source",
            "Source directory"
        );

        var destinationOption = new Option<DirectoryInfo>(
            "--destination",
            "Destination directory"
        );

        var rootCommand = new RootCommand("Test app for argument parsing")
        {
            sourceOption,
            destinationOption
        };

        rootCommand.SetHandler<DirectoryInfo, DirectoryInfo>((source, destination) => {
            Console.WriteLine($"Source: {source?.FullName ?? "Not provided"}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Destination: {destination?.FullName ?? "Not provided"}");
        },
        sourceOption, destinationOption);

        return await rootCommand.InvokeAsync(args);
    }
}
```

If you pass in a path argument that ends in a trailing slash and map it to a DirectoryInfo object, it seems to interpret the trailing backslash as an escape character that escapes the closing quotation mark of the argument value and then interprets the rest of the command line arguments string as the rest of the argument value.

For example:
`myApp.exe --source "e:\source" --destination "e:\destination"` works as expected and outputs

```
Source: e:\source
Destination: e:\destination
```

However the following `--source "e:\source\" --destination "e:\destination"` the difference being the trailing slash on `"e:\source\"` parses incorrectly and outputs:

```
Source: e:\source" --destination e:\destination
Destination: Not provided
```

It appears to have interpreted this `\"` as an escape sequence for `"` and then  `--destination "e:\destination` as the rest of the `--source` argument.

I struggle to imagine a world in which this is intended behaviour but I would appreciate any feedback from other people before I log a bug report.

Comment: I think use ``\`` to escape ``"`` should be an expected behavior for programmers, and it has nothing to do with the library or .net. This is how Windows parses the command line: [What's up with the strange treatment of quotation marks and backslashes by CommandLineToArgvW](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100917-00/?p=12833)